# Jquery Add row just after current and delete current row

Tags: jquery

I'm very new to jquery and I have trouble to understand how to make this work.

```js
$('.addline').click(function () {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var allTrs = $tr.closest('table').find('tr');
    var lastTr = allTrs[allTrs.length-1];
    var $clone = $(lastTr).clone();

    $clone.find('td').each(function() {
        var el = $(this).find(':first-child');
        var id = el.attr('id') || null;
        if(id) {
            var i = id.substr(id.length-1);
            var prefix = id.substr(0, (id.length-1));
            el.attr('id', prefix+(+i+1));
            el.attr('name', prefix+(+i+1));
        }
    });

    $clone.find('input:text').val('');
    $tr.closest('table').append($clone);
});

// Remove row from the table
$('.Remline').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="fla_inf" width="100%">
<tr>
<th class="tab_header" colspan="6">Flavors and Additives</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th class="tab_header_nam">Flavor Brand</th>
    <th class="tab_header_nam">Flavor Name</th>
    <th class="tab_header_nam">Dropper Type</th>
    <th class="tab_header_nam">Quantity</th>
    <th class="tab_header_nam">Total %</th>
    <th class="tab_header_nam">Add/Remove row</th>
</tr>
<tbody>
<tr>
     <td><select id="marque.0" name="marque,0"></select></td>
     <td><select id="arome.0" name="arome.0"></select></td>
     <td><select id="dropper.0" name="dropper.0"></select></td>
     <td><input id="quantity.0" name="quantity.0" type="number"/></td>
     <td><input id="fla_perc.0" name="fla_perc.0" type="number" min="0" max="100"/></td>
     <td><input class="addline" type="button" value="Add row" /><input class="remline" type="button" value="Remove row" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I have two issues with my JS code:

1. I can add a row only by clicking the last Add row button, I would like to be able to add a row just after the one where I clicked "add row".
2. Nothing happens when I click on "Remove row".

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you try replacing `var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');` with `var $tr = $(this).parent('tr');`

Comment: @zaitsman If `closest` doesn't return anything, `parent` won't.

Comment: Your code doesn't work in Firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you register an event on a DOM element, jQuery only adds handles to elements currently present on the page, so if you add a new DOM element after registering event, that new element will not have any handles. An easy solution is registering events on the `document` instead.

This works as you expect:

```
$(document).on('click', '.addline', function () {
    // code for adding line
});

$(document).on('click', '.remline', function () {
    // code for removing line
});
```

Also, as @vbouk already mentioned, you have a typo in your selector. `Remline` and `remline` are different selectors in CSS.

---

Working example:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.addline', function() {
  var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var allTrs = $tr.closest('table').find('tr');
  var lastTr = allTrs[allTrs.length - 1];
  var $clone = $(lastTr).clone();

  $clone.find('td').each(function() {
    var el = $(this).find(':first-child');
    var id = el.attr('id') || null;
    if (id) {
      var i = id.substr(id.length - 1);
      var prefix = id.substr(0, (id.length - 1));
      el.attr('id', prefix + (+i + 1));
      el.attr('name', prefix + (+i + 1));
    }
  });

  $clone.find('input:text').val('');
  $tr.closest('table').append($clone);
});

// Remove row from the table
$(document).on('click', '.remline', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="fla_inf" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <th class="tab_header" colspan="6">Flavors and Additives</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="tab_header_nam">Flavor Brand</th>
    <th class="tab_header_nam">Flavor Name</th>
    <th class="tab_header_nam">Dropper Type</th>
    <th class="tab_header_nam">Quantity</th>
    <th class="tab_header_nam">Total %</th>
    <th class="tab_header_nam">Add/Remove row</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select id="marque.0" name="marque,0"></select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select id="arome.0" name="arome.0"></select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select id="dropper.0" name="dropper.0"></select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="quantity.0" name="quantity.0" type="number" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="fla_perc.0" name="fla_perc.0" type="number" min="0" max="100" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="addline" type="button" value="Add row" />
        <input class="remline" type="button" value="Remove row" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you for providing the answer, the correct code is :

```
 // Add row to the table by cloning existing row
 $(document).on('click', '.addline', function(){

    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var allTrs = $tr.closest('table').find('tr');
    var lastTr = allTrs[allTrs.length-1];
    var $clone = $(lastTr).clone();
    $clone.find('td').each(function(){
        var el = $(this).find(':first-child');
        var id = el.attr('id') || null;
        if(id) {
            var i = id.substr(id.length-1);
            var prefix = id.substr(0, (id.length-1));
            el.attr('id', prefix+(+i+1));
            el.attr('name', prefix+(+i+1));
        }
    });
    $clone.find('input:text').val('');
    $tr.closest('table').append($clone);
});

// Remove row from the table
$(document).on('click', '.remline', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Like Jev mentioned in the answer handlers for new objects are not added unless your register them in the document itself.

Comment: I understand, thank you very much for your help, all my code is in a js file which is loaded when the page loads. In this js I already have a 
jQuery(function ($) {
how can I include whan you explain in it, just replacing 
    $('.addline').click(function ()
by
    $(document).click('.addline', function ()
doesn't work.
How can I workaround this.

Comment: `$(document).click('.addline', function() {})` works from everywhere, no matter where your JS is being loaded. You might want to increase the specificity of a selector if `.addline` is too generic or used elsewhere in your project.

Comment: Hi,
I tried it here to be sure it's not intereacting with something else but it doesn't work either :
http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=Mv4KsetqwL

Comment: That's right. It should be `$(document).on('click', '.addline', function() {})`. I've adjusted my answer accordingly

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working fine, I'll update my post accordingly too.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine you have a typo in the remove function. your class name is `remline`

it should be like this

```
// Remove row from the table
    $('.remline').click(function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
```